# How to make a pause and resume in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-development, pause, resume

I have been having trouble making a pause and resume function in my game, i can click the pause button once and it will work and bring up the resume button but when i click the resume button nothing happens, i believe it is caused by my if else statement which locks the game into the paused state and doesn't allow it to come back out but i don't know how to solve this issue.

```
paused = False
resumed = False


def run_game():
    global paused
    if pause_button.clicked:
        paused = True
        resume_button.resume_button_visible = True
        resume_button.draw()
        print(paused)
    else:
        boxer_1.update()
        boxer_2.update()

        draw_health_bar(boxer_1.health, 50, 30)
        draw_health_bar(boxer_2.health, 650, 30)

        boxer_1.move(SCREEN_WIDTH, screen, boxer_2)
        boxer_2.move_enemy(SCREEN_WIDTH, screen, boxer_1)

        boxer_1.draw(screen)
        boxer_2.draw(screen)

        paused = False
        resume_button.resume_button_visible = False
        pause_button.draw()
        print(paused)

run = True
while run:
    draw_bg()

    clock.tick(FPS)

    start_button.draw()
    exit_button.draw()
    if start_button.clicked or resume_button.clicked:
        run_game()
        exit_button.visible = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            print('if x button is pressed game will stop')
            run = False
            sys.exit()

    if exit_button.clicked:
        run = False
        print('game will stop')

    pygame.display.update()

sys.exit()
```

Here is the code for the button

```
import pygame

# Screen width, and height in pixels
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1000
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500

# Set screen size and caption
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Fighter Game Menu!')


class Button:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), (int(height * scale))))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self):
        action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        left_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

        if self.visible:
            screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

            if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):

                if left_click == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                    self.clicked = True
                    self.visible = False
                    action = True

                elif left_click == 0:
                    self.clicked = False

            return action


class Pause(Button):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        Button.__init__(self, x, y, image, scale)
        self.resume_button_visible = False

    def draw(self):
        pause_action = False
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        left_click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

        if self.resume_button_visible:
            screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

            if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):

                if left_click == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                    self.clicked = True
                    pause_action = True
                elif left_click == 1 and self.clicked == True:
                    self.clicked = False
                    pause_action = False
                elif left_click == 0:
                    self.clicked = False

            return pause_action
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can u make the code reproducible ?

Answer (score 0):

When the pause button is clicked, you could set a flag to stop everything else and show the resume button

when the resume button is clicked, set that flag back to false